# KeyError-Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to run this block of iteration code:

```
row_list = []

for idx, (index, row) in enumerate(data.iterrows()):
    mn = row[pm_cols].mean()
    if not math.isnan(mn):
        temp_row = row[features_columns]
        temp_row['PM'] = mn
        row_list.append(temp_row)
    if idx % 1000 ==0 and idx != 0:
        print(idx)
```

And got back the message: KeyError: "Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported. The following labels were missing: Index(['PM'], dtype='object'). See [https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike"](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike%22)

Instruction guide from Pandas.pydata does not address my concern, as the solution is suitable for indexing. In my case, my intention is to append all rows that does not contain "NaN" values into a new "temp_row" dataframe.